# Python String Converter; how do I convert a string in python

Tags: python, string

Suppose there is a string as ("Hello! Python is a great language!") then how would I convert Hello! into hijkefghlmnolmnoopqr! If h=hijk e=efgh l=lmno o=opqrs and so for rest of the string?

Comment: I.e. for each letter in a string you want to insert the three letters that follow it in the alphabet?

Comment: if so, what should happen to x, y, z?

Comment: "Welcome to stack overflow, please show what you have tried and hasn't worked".

Comment: In this case but in larger picture I should be able to insert any values in place of each alphabet

Comment: Strings are immutable. Otherwise: Read a primer about Python!

Comment: x = xyza y=yzab z=zabc

Comment: You need to show an attempt at solving the problem yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LETTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc"

def translate_char(ch):
    i = LETTERS.find(ch.lower())
    if i == -1:
        return ch
    else:
        return LETTERS[i:i + 4]

def translate_string(s):
    return "".join(translate_char(ch) for ch in s)

print(translate_string("Hello!"))   # =>  hijkefghlmnolmnoopqr!
```

Comment: I believe `ord` could be used to avoid a linear (`O(n)`) search on `ch.lower()`, but the impact would be fairly negligible

Comment: For what it's worth: I agree that Steven's dict-based answer is more efficient (and upvoted it!). I was going for a more step-by-step, easier-to-understand explanation for a new user.

Answer (score 2):

```
subs = {}
alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabc'
for i in range(26):
    subs[alpha[i]] = alpha[i:i+4]
s = "Hello! Python is a great language!"
s = ''.join(subs.get(c, c) for c in s.lower())
```